# Proof of order limit theorem in Stephen Abbot's book

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Assume $\lim{a_n}=a$ and $\lim{b_n}=b$
> (i) If $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a\ge0$.
> (ii) If $a_n \le b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a\le b$
> (iii) If there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $c \le b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $c \le b$. Similarly,
> if $a_n \le c$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a \le c$.

Abbot proves (i) by contradiction: he first pretend that $a$ is lower than zero, and shows that $a_n$ becomes negative as the direct consequence.

For (ii), he uses algebraic limit theorem to show $b_n - a_n$ converges to $b-a$, and applies the same logic used while proving (i).

What I could not figure out was the proof of (iii). In his book, he says:

> Take $a_n = c$ (or $b_n = c$) for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and apply (ii).

I could only assume that Abbot is taking $a_n =c$ because this is the *worst case scenario* that touches the borderline of inequality, but I am neither sure if I am correct nor know how to progress with that logic. I have watched a youtube video that proves (iii) using a constant series($s_n=c$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$) and that made sense to me. What was the actual approach that Abbott is taking here?

Comment: Abbot is doing precisely what was done in the video you describe. Note that the text from the book that you cite--"Take $a_n = c$ (or $b_n = c$) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$"--means "take $a_n$ (or $b_n$) to be the constant sequence $a_n$ (resp., $b_n$) $= c$."

Comment: @user1090793 Oh, does that mean we are subtracting a constant sequence $a_n$ from the first equation($c \le b_n$) so that it becomes $0 \le b_n - a_n$ ? Not applying the condition to the second equation($c \le a_n$).

Comment: We don't need to do this. Just suppose you have some sequence $b_n$ with $\lim b_n = b$ and that for $c$ a fixed constant, $c \leq b_n$ for all $n$. Then we can define a sequence $a_n$ by $a_n = c$ for all $n$. Clearly, $\lim a_n = c$. and $a_n \leq b_n$. By part (ii), $c \leq b$. A similar argument shows that for a sequence $a_n$ with $\lim a_n = a$ and $a_n \leq c$ for all $n$, $a \leq c$.

Comment: This is a long winded way of rephrasing Abbot's proof of (iii)

Comment: @user1090793 This resolves my confusion. I thought we are taking $a_n=c$ and applying this condition to the second equation($a_n \le c$) and respectively $b_n=c$ to the first one.